# Lua: Connect with MSSQL DB

Tags: database, lua

I'm learning about Lua (version 5.3),Is there a way to connect to an mssql database?
I try to do it as follows

```
print("Connection to the db:")
local dbuser = '....'
local dbpass = '...'
local dbsource = '....'
local dbname = 'xx.xx.xxx.xx'
database.open("Provider= ODBC ; Initial Catalog = dbname; Data Source = dbsource ; User ID = dbuser ; Password = dbpass ")
print("Database opened succesfully.")
print("Connection to the db:")
```

But didn´t work, execution returns me:

```
 attempt to index a nil value (global 'database')
```

Thanks,

Comment: Standard Lua has no module/function that provides data base access.  You must use a specific binary module to extend Lua with this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to do it as follows
>
> ```
> database.open("Provider= ODBC ; Initial Catalog = dbname; Data Source = dbsource ; User ID = dbuser ; Password = dbpass ")
> ```

What made you think you can do that? You get that error because there is no global variable `database` unless you define one.
Hence you may not index it. Trial and error with random code is not a very good way to get things done in programming.

Also you cannot handle strings like that in Lua. You either need to use `string.format` or the concatenation operator `..` to get your variables into that string.

There's also no `printf` in Lua unless you define it.

I suggest you learn the basics of Lua befor you get into interfacing databases.

From reading the Lua reference manual it should become obvious that Lua does not know anything about databases.

Either you run Lua embedded into some host application that provides database access through its Lua API or you need to load a library that supports that.

Searching the web for "lua sql" instantly yields

https://keplerproject.github.io/luasql/

and others.

Comment: @thanks Piglet! It was a code example I found "googling".

Comment: FYI the link is dead now